# What are these controls?

Tags: android, android-library

I need some controls to do an app like the image. Which library can I use?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First could be something like this: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Second could be something like this: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Also have a look at [DevAppsDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) which has a lot of demos of different opensource projects.

Hope this helps.